# Implicit conversion between c++11 clocks/time_points

Tags: date, c++11, time, c++-chrono

Is it possible to do implicit/explicit conversion between `time_point`s of two C++11 clocks?

**Motivation:** `chrono::duration`s provide means of storing time intervals from epoch, conceptually is not equal to a `time_point` of a custom clock that has an epoch on its own.
Having an implicit conversion between clocks eases up the use Howard Hinnant's [date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) `<date/date.h>` which provides means to manipulate and print out `time_point`s of system clocks.

**Example:**

```
#include <date/date.h>
using namespace date;
namespace ch = std::chrono;
// 
#define EPOCH_OFFSET 100
template<class Duration> using PosixTimePoint = 
                   ch::time_point<ch::system_clock, Duration>;
typedef PosixTimePoint<ch::duration<long,std::micro>> PosixTimePointType;

struct SomeClock{
    typedef ch::duration<long,std::micro>   duration;
    typedef ch::time_point<SomeClock>  time_point;

    ...
    static time_point now() noexcept {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        return time_point (
            duration_cast<duration>( 
                system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()) + date::years(EPOCH_OFFSET) );
    }
    static PosixTimePoint<duration> to_posix( const time_point& tp  ){...}

}
auto tp = SomeClock::now(); //<time_point<SomeClock,ch::duration<long,std::micro>>;
```

**Objective:** to convert `tp` so the `std::stream` conversions of `date.h` works and prints out the current time, which in my case is: *2017-12-24 17:02:56.000000*

```
// std::cout << tp; compile error
std::cout << SomeClock::to_posix( tp ); // OK
```

**Explicit cast:** this could ease up readability, support conversion feature of the language and facilitate access to `date.h` routines.

```
long time_value = static_cast<long>( tp );
auto st = static_cast<PosixTimePointType>( tp ); 
std::cout << static_cast<PosixTimePointType>( tp );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend mimicking the implementations of either `date::utc_clock` or `date::tai_clock` found in [tz.h](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/tz.h). For example `utc_clock` implements two functions to convert to and from `sys_time`:

```
template<typename Duration>
static
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, typename std::common_type<Duration, std::chrono::seconds>::type>
to_sys(const std::chrono::time_point<utc_clock, Duration>&);

template<typename Duration>
static
std::chrono::time_point<utc_clock, typename std::common_type<Duration, std::chrono::seconds>::type>
from_sys(const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration>&);
```

So you can think of `std::chrono::system_clock` as a "hub".  Any clock that implements these conversions can convert to any other clock which implements these conversions by bouncing off of `system_clock` under the covers.  And to facilitate that bounce, [`date::clock_cast`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#clock_cast) is introduced.

Additionally, `utc_time` can be used as the hub, if that is more efficient for your type.  For example `tai_clock` implements:

```
template<typename Duration>
static
std::chrono::time_point<utc_clock, typename std::common_type<Duration, std::chrono::seconds>::type>
to_utc(const std::chrono::time_point<tai_clock, Duration>&) NOEXCEPT;

template<typename Duration>
static
std::chrono::time_point<tai_clock, typename std::common_type<Duration, std::chrono::seconds>::type>
from_utc(const std::chrono::time_point<utc_clock, Duration>&) NOEXCEPT;
```

`clock_cast` is smart enough to deal with this "dual-hub" system, so one can convert a clock that converts to/from `utc_time`, to another clock that uses `sys_time` as its hub.

If you also implement `to_stream` for your clock, then you can directly use `format` to format your `clock::time_point`.  And `clock_cast` is likely to be useful in the implementation of your `to_stream` function.

Also `from_stream` can be used to hook your `clock::time_point` up to `date::parse`.

Search https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html for "`clock_cast`" for example uses of it.  For your use case the `to_sys`/`from_sys` API appears to be the most useful.  Just these two functions will allow you to use `clock_cast` between your `SomeClock` and any other clock in tz.h (and any other custom clock that meets these requirements).

---

### Full Demo

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct SomeClock
{
    using duration = std::chrono::microseconds;
    using rep = duration::rep;
    using period = duration::period;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<SomeClock>;
    static constexpr bool is_steady = false;

    static time_point now() noexcept
    {
        return from_sys(date::floor<duration>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()));
    }

    static constexpr auto offset = date::sys_days{} - date::sys_days{date::year{1870}/1/1};

    template<typename Duration>
    static
    date::sys_time<Duration>
    to_sys(const std::chrono::time_point<SomeClock, Duration>& t)
    {
        return date::sys_time<Duration>{(t - offset).time_since_epoch()};
    }

    template<typename Duration>
    static
    std::chrono::time_point<SomeClock, Duration>
    from_sys(const date::sys_time<Duration>& t)
    {
        return std::chrono::time_point<SomeClock, Duration>{(t + offset).time_since_epoch()};
    }
};

template <class Duration>
using SomeTime = std::chrono::time_point<SomeClock, Duration>;

constexpr date::days SomeClock::offset;

template <class CharT, class Traits, class Duration>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
to_stream(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, const CharT* fmt,
          const SomeTime<Duration>& t)
{
    return date::to_stream(os, fmt, date::clock_cast<std::chrono::system_clock>(t));
}

template <class CharT, class Traits, class Duration>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, const SomeTime<Duration>& t)
{
    const CharT fmt[] = {'%', 'F', ' ', '%', 'T', CharT{}};
    return to_stream(os, fmt, t);
}

template <class Duration, class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc = std::allocator<CharT>>
std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>&
from_stream(std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& is, const CharT* fmt,
            SomeTime<Duration>& tp, std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Alloc>* abbrev = nullptr,
            std::chrono::minutes* offset = nullptr)
{
    using namespace date;
    sys_time<Duration> st;
    date::from_stream(is, fmt, st, abbrev, offset);
    if (!is.fail())
        tp = clock_cast<SomeClock>(st);
    return is;
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << SomeClock::now() << '\n';
    std::cout << date::format("%a, %b %d, %Y\n", SomeClock::now());
    std::istringstream in{"2017-12-24 19:52:30"};
    SomeClock::time_point t;
    in >> date::parse("%F %T", t);
    std::cout << t << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Wonderful Christmas present, thank you! For some reasons  when using float/double underlying representation the stream fails for sys_time. Am I making a mistake or I supposed to make a duration cast to integer rep type, then a clock_cast as you outlined 'bounce back from sys_time' method?

Comment: For formatting, cast to an integral rep type with precision indicating the number of fractional digits you wish to appear for seconds.  For example, if you want 3 fractional digits for seconds, `floor<milliseconds>(t)`.